# Fullcalendar timelineview - Restore scroll position

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

I have used Full calendar timeline view. timeline view is auto refresh every 30 seconds using **setInterval(function () { refreshEvents(); }, 30000);**

For refresh i have used **removeEvents** and **addEventSource**
So i need to get vertical scroll position of timelineview before removeEvents and restore scroll position after addEventSource because every refresh scroll position is lost

So how can i restore scroll position of timeline view while auto refresh event

See below code :

```
$('#divCalendar').fullCalendar({
        resourceAreaWidth: 200,
        allDaySlot: false,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
        slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
        eventDurationEditable: false,
        header: {
                    left: 'today prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'timelineDay',
                },
         views: {
                    timelineDay: {
                        type: 'timeline',
                        slotDuration: '00:02:00'
                    }
                },
        resources: function (callback) {
                    // necessary hack
                    var view = $('#divCalendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Dispatcher/GetTimeLineDriverList',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                            start: view.start.format(),
                            end: view.end.format()
                        }
                    }).then(function (resources) {
                        callback(resources);
                    });
                },
        events: {
                    url: '/Dispatcher/GetDriverTripSchedules'
                },
});

 function refreshEvents() {
                var calenderDate = $('#divCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format("MM-DD-YYYY");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Dispatcher/GetDriverTripSchedules',
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#divCalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        $('#divCalendar').fullCalendar("addEventSource", response);
                    }
                });

}

 setInterval(function () { refreshEvents(); }, 30000);
```

Comment: I also facing same issue

Comment: I tried this: var scrollPosition = document.querySelector('.fc-scroller').scrollTop;  for getting current scroll position but it returns always return 0

Answer (score 0):

The only way I solve this is by saving the scrollbar position (in pixel) before the refresh and then reset after the refresh.

- Open the browser inspector
- Right click on the fullcalendar scrollbar and choose inspect
- Right click on the element selected in the inspector
- Select "Copy selector"

You should get something like this:

```
"#calendar > div.fc-view-harness.fc-view-harness-active > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > div > div"
```

To save the position:

```
let querySel = "#calendar > div.fc-view-harness.fc-view-harness-active > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > div > div"
let position = document.querySelector(querySel).scrollLeft
```

To re-set the previous position:

```
document.querySelector(querySel).scrollLeft = position
```

Note that you can use .scrollLeft or .scrollTop depending on your type of view.

This should reset the old position.